# how to allocate system-V shared memory between 2 process

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

recently, I try to create shared_memory between 2 process(host & guest),
and a structure named `my_shared` allocate in this memory.
but the struct have a pointer `int *`, I need to point out a
part of memory to him, here is my code:

**shared.h**

```
#define KEY 5114
struct my_shared{
    int *a;
    int b;
};
void *mem;
```

**host.c**

```
#include <...>
#include "shared.h"

struct my_shared *st;

int main(void)
{
    int id;
    key_t key = KEY;

    id = shmget(key, 1024, 0666|IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);//1K shared memory
    if(id < 0){/* do error handle */}

    mem = shmat(id, (void *)0, 0);
    if(mem == MAP_FAILED){/* do error handle */}

    //point out the shared memory base address
    st = (struct my_shared *)mem;
    //point out the int *a memory address
    st->a = (int *)(mem + sizeof(struct my_shared));

    //read-write the memory
    int i = 0;
    do{
       st->b = i++;
       *(st->a) = ++i;
       printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", st->b, *(st->a));
       sleep(1);
    }while(1);

    shmdt(st);
    return 0;
}
```

**guest.c**

```
#include <...>
#include "shared.h"

struct my_shared *st;

int main(void)
{
    int id;
    key_t key = KEY;

    id = shmget(key, 1024, 0); //1K shared memory
    if(id < 0){/* do error handle */}

    mem = shmat(id, (void *)0, 0);
    if(mem == MAP_FAILED){/* do error handle */}

    //point out the shared memory base address
    st = (struct my_shared *)mem;
    //point out the int *a memory address
    st->a = (int *)(mem + sizeof(struct my_shared));

    //read the memory
    do{
       printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", st->b, *(st->a));
       sleep(3);
    }while(1);

    shmdt(st);
    return 0;
}
```

If only execute `host` is fine, but when execute `guest` read the *(st->b) will lead `host` crush, gdb says *(st->a) cannot access for `host`,

If I modify the code, let `host` and `guest` only access st->b, it's work fine!

why access *(st->a) will crush? Am I lost something?

My env is ubuntu 14.04LTS with gcc4.8.5

Comment: You are changing the `st->a` value in both `host` and `guest`. That means they will at some point see the wrong value of `st->a`. You must not modify the shared `st->a` value in at least one of the processes.

Comment: thx for reply, but I only change `st->a` value in `host`, `guest` just read the value of `st->a`?

Comment: Really? Then what is this you are showing in guest.c: `st->a = (int *)(mem + sizeof(struct my_shared));` And if you don't set `st->a` in the guest then you MUST NOT dereference it. The value it has is not valid if it is set by another process.

Comment: as you mean, changing the value of shared_memory by another process is invalid?

Comment: Accessing a pointer from another process is invalid. Just because you name both variables with the same name `mem` does not mean they are the same values. shmat will in general map the shared memory to different addresses.

Comment: Got it, very thanks,
btw, if I remove the `shmat` in `guest`, is that OK?

Comment: No it is not ok. If you remove the shmat then guest will not be able to see the shared struct. So that would defeat the purpose of having a shared memory area.

Comment: Additionally, you need to "serialize" access to your shared memory segment (usually with a semaphore) to protect from partial updates.  Much the same as you would do in a multi-threaded program accessing "global" memory with a Mutex.

Comment: Many thx, @kaylum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing pointers in shared memory can't work because the block usually is located in different addresses in each process.

But there is a solution: pass the difference between the pointer itself and the pointer to the shared block. That way, the client just adds its base address to the value inside, and has a valid pointer to the data. Of course, the pointer in the server must point to a zone inside the same shared memory block.